# Using Salesforce Flow to create mutiple child records

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

I am working on a solution for the following:

We have a multi-select picklist on the Opportunity that (currently) has four values: value1, value2, value3, value4

When a new value is selected and saved, it will need to create a child record; let's call the object valueChildRecord__c.

This is easy enough to do using Process Builder if it was for a single-select picklist. However, if the Opportunity is saved with value1, value2, and value3 selected, it will need to create 3 child records with each respective value stored in a field in its corresponding record.

The next part is slightly more complicated. If the Opportunity is edited and value3 is deselected and saved, the child record that corresponds to value3 needs to be updated with a timestamp. This goes for each value, and only if the value is deselected. If, in the future, value3 is selected and saved, it should create a new record.

I understand that I will need to use Process Builder and have a Flow trigger off of it. However, I have no idea where to begin with creating the Flow. A lot of the Salesforce help pages are very shallow, whereas I need a very indepth step-by-step guide to do something like this.

Can someone verify that using a process and flow in this way is the right approach? Any assistance in the actual building of the flow or a point in the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: Go to [Salesforce Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules) and search for process builder modules and Flow modules.

Comment: Is `PRIORVALUE()` supported on multi-selects in Flow formulas? It's not shown in the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tips_for_using_picklist_formula_fields.htm&type=5). That doesn't make the Flow impossible, but trickier.

Answer (score 0):

A flow inside of PB is the correct way to do this. There's a Trailhead module that covers this particular topic called [Lightning Flow](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/business_process_automation). It's one of the more recent ones and should give you enough to get you started on what you're trying to do. I'd also highly recommend looking at the Automation Champion Blog for additional help on the topic. He really knows this material inside out.